# Find all records having less value then sum of two columns with associated activerecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

I have a Room model and it is associated with ReservationRoom. (**room => has_many :reservations_rooms**)

Now I want to find Rooms with below condition

ReservationRooms has two column named **number_of_adults** and **number_of_child**

and

Room has column named **min_occupancy**

I need all the room record

if **sum of the number_of_adults and number_of_child** of reservation_rooms, less then **min_occupancy** of room table.

something link below.

`Room.joins(:reservations_rooms).where(id: [22, 19]).having('sum(reservations_rooms.number_of_adult + reservations_rooms.number_of_child) < rooms.min_occupancy')`

can someone help me out with this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this, I think you don't need grouping

```
Room.joins(:reservation_rooms).
  where(rooms: { id: [22, 19] }).
  where('reservation_rooms.number_of_adults + reservation_rooms.number_of_child <= rooms.min_occupancy')
```

I left the condition about ids because I don't know if you need that too

Comment: it give me this error

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "number_of_adults" does not exist
LINE 1: ... "rooms"."id" WHERE "rooms"."id" IN ($1, $2) AND (number_of_...
                                                             ^
HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the column "reservations_rooms.number_of_adult".

because number_of_adults and number_of_child belongs to reservations_room table. but i had also try with **where('reservations_rooms.number_of_adults + reservations_rooms.number_of_child < min_occupancy')** but same result. Thanks for reply.

Comment: try `reservation_rooms.number_of_adults` and `reservation_rooms.number_of_child`. `reservation`, not `reservations`

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a `where` clause. You can combine multiple `where` in ActiveRecord and the will be combined with `AND`:

```rb
Room                             # the model you are interested in
  .joins(:reservation_rooms)     # combine the reservations
  .where(rooms: {id: [22, 19]})  # only for those two rooms
  .where(
    "number_of_adults + number_of_child <= min_occupancy"
  )                              # add adults/child and compare to occupancy
```

This should generate SQL similar to this.

```sql
select * from rooms
joins reservation_rooms on roomws.id = reservation_rooms.room_id
where 
  rooms.id in (22, 19)
  and number_of_adults + number_of_child <= max_occupancy
```

Some notes:

- You can see what SQL gets generated by appending `.to_sql` to your ActiveRecord::Association (the query you've built)
- Assuming the column names are unique you don't need to prefix them with the table name (e.g. if bot tables have a `created_at` column you would need to specify what column you are interested in like `rooms.id`).
- I'd rename `number_of_child` to `number_of_children` to be consistent (it's plural on `number_of_adults`)
- `sum` is an aggregate function (like `avg`, `count` and others). Those functions are used to *group* multiple columns into one. (in your example you want to combine multiple columns of a row, hence you can use `+`)
- `having` is also used with *group* s. It is similar to a `where` clause but for filtering `group`ed rows